# Use NGINX on Azure VM to load balance to other Azure VMs

Tags: java, azure, nginx, load-balancing, azure-virtual-network

I'm running NGINX Open Source on an Ubuntu 17.10 VM in Azure `(VM1)`. I want to use it as a load balancer to forward TCP traffic to more Ubuntu VMs in the same Azure subscription. Currently I just have one additional VM `(VM2)` behind the NGINX server to keep it simple.

Locally, I have a Java program that generates a TCP message and sends it to the NGINX server's public IP on port 6050. That VM has an inbound security rule allowing traffic on port 6050. It should then send that traffic to my second VM's public IP on port 6060. That VM has an inbound rule for port 6060.

Here is my `nginx.conf` file:

```
user                    nginx;
worker_processes        1;
error_log               /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid                     /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

stream {
    upstream backend {
        server <VM2 public IP>:6060;
    }

    server {
        listen 6050;
        proxy_pass backend;
    }
}
```

There are no errors in `error.log`, but the TCP traffic never shows up on port 6060 on VM2.

This seems like a fairly simple use case, but I can't for the life of me figure out why the traffic isn't going through. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out. My VM running NGINX was behind an Azure load balancer, which I wasn't using anymore. My guess is for VM's connected to a load balancer, you can't directly send traffic to them. You would have to send the traffic to their load balancer.

Solution: I created a new VM, not attached to any Azure load balancer. Installed NGINX fresh and hooked it up to my destination VM. Worked perfectly.

Comment: If the issue has been resolved, you could accept your reply as an answer.

Comment: Trying to- SO won't let me accept it for 8 more hours.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use Nginx plus and this clearly used to load balance HTTP based LB working on layer 7 functionality.